# Is that possible to separate socket listeners but keep the logic of useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

this is the code i have in my app.js

```
    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on(activechat.chatid, (bdmsg) => {
            chatMsgStore.addChatMsg(bdmsg)
        })
        return () => {
            socket.off(activechat.chatid)
        }
    }, [activechat, chatMsgStore.chatmsg])
```

moving further the amount of socket listeners will grow
and i would like to move the **socket.on listeners** to another separate file but i want to keep the logic of useEffect with cleanup function
how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the logic into a custom react hook to make the component clear.

E.g.

`useChat.js`:

```js
function useChat() {
  //...
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on(activechat.chatid, (bdmsg) => {
      chatMsgStore.addChatMsg(bdmsg)
    });
    return () => {
      socket.off(activechat.chatid)
    };
  }, [activechat, chatMsgStore.chatmsg])
  //...
}
```

If the listener's logic is complex, extract it into a domain service to handle the business logic. The logic inside `useChat` hook becomes thin.

`useChat.js`:

```js
function useChat() {
  //...
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on(activechat.chatid, chatService.handler);
    return () => {
      socket.off(activechat.chatid)
    };
  }, [activechat, chatMsgStore.chatmsg])
  //...
}
```

`chatService.js`:

```js
function handler(bdmsg) {
  chatMsgStore.addChatMsg(bdmsg);
  // Put complex logic here
}
```